# android recycleview using with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-recyclerview

Currently, I am working on a project that has a navigation drawer, and I am using fragments for the stuff. I was about to user a recycle view for it, but I get a problem with the code, specifically when I try to add the `LayoutInflater`, and stick it into my fragment that should be using the `layoutinflater.from(fragment.getBaseContext);`  which isn't working

That is the code that works on the usual Activity, but it doesn't seem to work with a .fragment activity

Can anybody help me with this? or even point me in the right direction?

```
package sample.101.sample.fragment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyRecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecycleViewHolder> {

    Bad_house_list bad_house_list;
    ArrayList<User> userArrayList;

    public MyRecycleViewAdapter(Bad_house_list bad_house_list, ArrayList<User> userArrayList) {
        this.bad_house_list = bad_house_list;
        this.userArrayList = userArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyRecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Bad_house_list.getBaseContext());
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent,false);


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecycleViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @user1868185 please post your code as text and not image.

Comment: hey Diego i updated it with the code , please remember i am using fragments and with a navigation drawer for it T_T , the code works in just the ordinary activity but it doesnt seem to work properly on a fragment T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this !

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_answer, parent, false);
view.setOnClickListener(this);
view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
MyCustomHolderClass myCustomHolder = new MyCustomHolderClass(view);
return myCustomView;
```

Comment: thanks dude , seems your's work properly , now the biggest question is will i get an error when i finish this up or not :D, also the help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your adapter with this

```
package sample.101.sample.fragment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyRecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecycleViewHolder> {

Bad_house_list bad_house_list;
ArrayList<User> userArrayList;

public MyRecycleViewAdapter(Bad_house_list bad_house_list, ArrayList<User> userArrayList) {
    this.bad_house_list = bad_house_list;
    this.userArrayList = userArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyRecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

 View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
 return new MyRecycleViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyRecycleViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userArrayList.size();
}
}
```